# Binding UserControl View model on MainWindow with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I am newbie to WPF and MVVM and I am trying to learn how WPF working with MVVM.  For that,  I have made a sample as follows

### **UserControl1.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox   Text="{Binding MyString}" />
</StackPanel>
```

### **UserControl1ViewModel.cs**

```
class UserControl1ViewModel
{
     public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

### **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding UC1Property}"/>  //tried binding the Usercontrol1VM obj on MainWindowVM
        <Button Command="{Binding ShowMeOne}" Height="30" Content="ShowOne"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding ShowMeAnother}" Height="30" Content="ShowAnother" />
</StackPanel>
```

### **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

### **MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ShowMeOne = new RelayCommand(Prompt_ShowMeOne);
        ShowMeAnother = new RelayCommand(Prompt_ShowMeAnother);
        UC1Property.MyString = "Initial";
    }

    private void Prompt_ShowMeAnother(object obj)
    {
        global::System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Another Should be shown");     
        UC1Property.MyString = "Last Clicked:  Another";
    }

    private void Prompt_ShowMeOne(object obj)
    {
        global::System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("One Should be shown");
        UC1Property.MyString = "Last Clicked:  One";
    }

    public ICommand ShowMeOne { get; set; }
    public ICommand ShowMeAnother { get; set; }


    //UserControl1 View Model for MainWindow
    public UserControl1ViewModel UC1Property { get; set; }


}
```

***Problem:*** Now, how can I pass the Datacontext of the Usercontrol into the MainWindow?

```
-----------------------------In MainWindow.xaml----------------------
<local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding UC1Property}"/>  //tried binding the Usercontrol1VM obj on MainWindowVM
-----------------------------In MainWindowViewModel.cs---------------
//UserControl1 View Model for MainWindow
public UserControl1ViewModel UC1Property { get; set; }
```

Above code which I tried is not working as expected.  What is the standard way of passing the datacontext of usercontrol over the window?

Comment: I think you want to reconsider this. Why would you use a UserControl is your main-view is bound to it like that?

Comment: @Stefan . . this is just a sample for better understanding. . I hope this is how it should be implemented. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Gopichandar: See my answer below. Custom user control's don't have their own ViewModel. They should be reusable and a ViewModel is something very specific to the application you are developing. MVVM pattern is there for application development, not for user controls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got a general misunderstanding here about MVVM, Views and UserControls.

A `UserControl` is a reusable piece of code, that is not specific to one kind of application. That being said, there is no `UserControl1ViewModel`, when you create a new `UserControl`.

A `UserControl` is self-sustained and all the logic your user control needs goes in there in code behind. To make it clear, this is **not** a violation of MVVM pattern. MVVM pattern applies to Views and ViewModels and how they interact.

There is a subtle difference between a `View` (pure XAML, no logic). Views also often inherit from `UserControl`, but a `View` is only good in the application you are developing right now. You are very unlikely to be able to reuse this in another application.

That's a difference, between the `UserControl`. For example, a calendar user control is reusable and all the logic to choose and display the calendar is part of it's control code behind and you can use it in many kind of applications.

When you create a `UserControl` which uses data-bindings, you need to expose dependency properties in your user control, on an date-picker user control this may be `MinDate`, `MaxDate`, `SelectedDate`, `FirstDayOfTheWeek` (Sunday or Monday) and/or properties that control the formatting and hide all other properties inside your `UserControl`s XAML (by not exposing them via Dependency Properties).

Comment: Aw! Really interesting. . I had a different mindset on MVVM and its implementation. Thanks for correcting me.