# NullReferenceException on DisplayRootViewFor<>

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, caliburn.micro

I've created a class derived from `BootstrapperBase`, overwrote `OnStartup()` and call `DisplayRootViewFor<AppViewModel>()` just like in the documentation.

But when i start the app, i get a `NullReferenceException` on `DisplayRooViewFor<AppViewModel>()`

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using MHBRestore.Logic;
using MHBRestore.UI.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace MHBRestore.UI
{
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<AppViewModel>();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override the `Configure` method and register your view model type:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        _container.RegisterPerRequest(typeof(AppViewModel), null, typeof(AppViewModel));
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<AppViewModel>();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
}
```